# How to convert string to array which string is array structere

Tags: php, arrays, string

I'm sending post array from swift to php server. Some issues my array looks like the server:

```
$my_array = $_POST['array'];
```

`$my_array` is  `["item1","item2","item3"]` but type is string not array.

I want to get array elements but when I try `$my_array[0]` is returning the first element of string `"` as you know.

I know I need to change my swift code but I wanna learn how can I convert these string to array and get elements.

Thanks

Comment: That line of code has invalid syntax. I suppose you need to add some escape characters... *"But type is string"*: then please use string-literal notation to reflect exactly what it is.

Comment: If fixed, that string looks like JSON. In that case you can do `$my_array = json_decode($str);`,  where `$str` is your string.

Comment: Ohh. Absolutely. Thanks @trincot. My mind is freeze :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `$_POST['array']` looks like JSON encoded.

If so, you can get the array with:

```
$my_array = json_decode($_POST['array']);
```